# scikit-image (io.imread) returns floating point array, is this already normalized?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, normalization, scikit-image

I'm importing grayscale images that are RGBA (4-channels) formatted using scikit-image.

```py
from skimage import io

example = io.imread("example.png", as_gray=True)
print(example.shape)
print(example)
plt.imshow(example)
```

I was expecting to get an array with values in the range 0-255. However, I found in the docs, that the above method returns an array of (64-bit) floating points.

Does this mean the values are already normalized (X / 255)? Or do I need to be aware of something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Min-Max Feature Scaling** aka **Min-Max Normalization / Unity-based Normalization** is a technique that brings all values in a set into the range [0, 1] (or an arbitrary range [a, b]).

The mathematical definition of min-max normalization is as follows:

[image]

Notice that calling `np.max(example)` will result in a value less than or equal to `1.0`.

Notice that calling `np.min(example)` will return a value greater than or equal to `0.0`.

*Yes, the features have been normalized **such that `a=0` and `b=255` in the equation above.***

Comment: This is a rather confusing answer, I think. We do not look at the data values when normalizing, but at the data type. Please also see https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/data_types.html

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect. The image is rescaled by 255, not by the image min/max.

Comment: Note that I mentioned the general definition for unity-based normalization. I hope it wasn't too confusing but nonetheless this is, in fact, an accurate answer. I clarified my answer regarding the scale to which the image is normalized.